# How to "reuse" randomly generated passwords in Helm and ArgoCD?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, argocd

I'm using ArgoCD to manage my app deployments. My apps are Helm charts and I'm using "randAlphaNum" to generate a random password. Unfortunately a new password is generated each time I'm syncing my app. So I was trying to use something like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mypass
type: Opaque
stringData:
{{ if .Release.IsInstall }}
  pw: {{ randAlphaNum 32 | quote }}
{{ end }}
```

But when I check the "App Diff", I see that ArgoCD also updates the "pw". So I tried using the "lookup" function of Helm instead but I finally figured out that it's not supported by ArgoCD atm (see https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/5202). So I wonder if there's any other solution I can use or if there's a list of supported Helm functions in ArgoCD?!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe an alternative way of generating passwords can help - try [Kubernetes Secret Generator](https://github.com/mittwald/kubernetes-secret-generator).

I've used this example to generate an auth secret for the chart bitnami/postgresql:

```yaml
apiVersion: secretgenerator.mittwald.de/v1alpha1
kind: StringSecret
metadata:
  name: postgresql-auth-secret
spec:
  forceRegenerate: false
  fields:
    - fieldName: "password"
      encoding: "base64"
      length: "30"
    - fieldName: "postgres-password"
      encoding: "base64"
      length: "30"
```

It seems to work well with ArgoCD too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to generate a value on the initial install and then never change it again, you should be able to leverage the `pre-install` hook to make sure that it is only ever used that first time:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mypass
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": "pre-install"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": "before-hook-creation"
type: Opaque
stringData:
  pw: {{ randAlphaNum 32 | quote }}
```

One caveat here is that by using a hook the resource will no longer be managed by Helm, so running `helm uninstall` would leave the secret behind, but the delete policy will make sure you don't get a collision on the next run.

Comment: I created a slightly more complicated example that allows for explicitly overriding the random value in the future if need be: https://github.com/brendonthiede/helm-random-testing

Comment: Based on what I found at https://itnext.io/manage-auto-generated-secrets-in-your-helm-charts-5aee48ba6918 I updated my repo to handle my scenario without using hooks. If the password will only be generated at install, using the hook seems cleaner to me, but to be able to update, the "lookup" approach works better, without always recreating the resource.

Comment: this does not work with ArgoCD